# Access programmatically WSO2 BAM registry

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I know I can access the WSO2 Governance Registry programmatically using the API. Is it also possible to access and upload/modify information on another (non GREG) servers'registry and how?

Is the approach the same? Is it possible to upload hive scripts for example on BAM programically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing embedded registry from a 'non GREG' WSO2 product using the registry API, is described here [1] in WSO2 Application Server documentation page.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/AS520/Basic+Registry+API+Knowledge

Thanks,
Isuruwan

Comment: Thanks Isuruwan! I've managed meanwhile to solve my problem using admin services to upload hive scripts. I'm going to give a try to embeded registry as well.